# Azure Webjob ImportError: No module named email_validator

Tags: python, azure, import, webjob

i'm trying to run  my python script on Azure web job, and its throwing this error

ImportError: No module named email_validator

```
[10/03/2019 18:57:16 > 7be10b: ERR ] Traceback (most recent call last):
[10/03/2019 18:57:16 > 7be10b: ERR ]   File "CheckEmail_Delta.py", line 14, in <module>
[10/03/2019 18:57:16 > 7be10b: ERR ]     from email_validator import validate_email, EmailNotValidError
[10/03/2019 18:57:16 > 7be10b: ERR ] ImportError: No module named email_validator
[10/03/2019 18:57:16 > 7be10b: SYS INFO] Status changed to Failed
[10/03/2019 18:57:16 > 7be10b: SYS ERR ] Job failed due to exit code 1
```

I've located my import package and added that to my script, but its still throwing the same error.

heres what i have

```py
import sys
sys.path.append("C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages")
sys.path.append("D:\home\site\wwwroot\env\Lib\site-packages")

import urllib2
import pypyodbc
import timestring
import datetime, time
import json, cookielib, pprint
import smtplib
import quickbase
#import pyqb
from email_validator import validate_email, EmailNotValidError
from json import dumps
```

any input appreciated. im using python 2.7

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out by adding the libraries directly into azure

Comment: how to do that? i have mydemo.py with import kiteconnect code . pls mention steps thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Besides your solution, we can use [virtual environment](https://help.dreamhost.com/hc/en-us/articles/215489338-Installing-and-using-virtualenv-with-Python-2) -> install all the necessary packages inside the virtual environment -> then send all the folders/files into a .zip file -> upload the .zip file to azure webjobs.